# Cannot click on anything when using Unity 3d

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

When i try to use Unity 3d, i can't click on anything. Can't drag and drop windows, can't focus on inputs etc.

Using Unity 2d works fine.

I have a Nvidia GTX 660 TI and the nvidia drivers are installed. Any ideas of why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Go in Unity 2D, launch Nautilus and do a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to display hidden files. Remove everything related to compiz (compiz, compiz-1, etc.) in:

1. /home/yourusername/
2. /home/yourusername/.config
3. /home/yourusername/.gconf/apps

Then close your Unity 2D session and try the standard Ubuntu session

Comment: You will have to reset the shorcuts in the left pannel.